# RealityKit override visualBounds() method for a subclass of Entity

Tags: swift, overriding, protocols, extension-methods, realitykit

I have a class inheriting from `Entity` like so:

```
class MyModelEntity: Entity, HasModel {
....
}
```

This class doesn't use `MeshResource` in a typical way so the model's positions are all set to 0,0,0 so `HasTransform.visualBounds` doesn't work correctly.  So I'm trying to provide a custom version for `MyModelEntity`.

I tried adding an overridden `visualBounds` method to `MyModelEntity`:

```
override func visualBounds(recursive: Bool = true, relativeTo referenceEntity: Entity?, excludeInactive: Bool = false) -> BoundingBox {
        return BoundingBox()
}
```

but the compiler says `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.

I then tried:

```
extension HasTransform where Self: MyModelEntity { 
   internal func visualBounds(recursive: Bool = true, relativeTo referenceEntity: Entity?, excludeInactive: Bool = false) -> BoundingBox {
        return BoundingBox()
    }
}
```

but that method never gets called from:

```
scene.performQuery(Self.MyQuery).forEach { entity in
    let bbox = entity.visualBounds(recursive: true, relativeTo: nil))
}
```

Thanks for any tips!